# Picasso not loading image for some url

Tags: android, image, picasso

I have an image that I want to download from online.
[http://luxproperty.kaytami.com/platform/media/image/jpeg/2014/12/24 Repulse Bay Road.jpg](http://luxproperty.kaytami.com/platform/media/image/jpeg/2014/12/24%20Repulse%20Bay%20Road.jpg)

I have replaced the space with %20, so it becomes
http://luxproperty.kaytami.com/platform/media/image/jpeg/2014/12/24%20Repulse%20Bay%20Road.jpg

The `image` is not large and so I assume Picasso should be able to load it.

To fit my imageview, I have fit() the image, and the code is as follow:

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(UrlEncoder.encode(district.getImage_urls().get(0))).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.image);
```

However, the image does not appear.

There is a list of 4 items, each containing an image that I load from online. three of them were loaded properly, and the remaining one (http://luxproperty.kaytami.com/platform/media/image/jpeg/2014/12/24%20Repulse%20Bay%20Road.jpg) just does not show up.

Any idea?

I am using Picasso 2.4.0, okhttp-2.1.0 have a look this

Comment: try removing fit and see if it works

Comment: It works if I remove fit(). Yet I would like to make the loaded image fit into my imageView, what should I do then?

Comment: try using centre crop or resize function of picasso

Comment: since I do not know the image size ratio beforehand, i cannot use resize. And is it that if i do not use fit() or resize(), then Picasso would download the full size of the image before putting it into the imageview? If that, then it would be time-consuming to load all the images. Any thoughts?

Comment: use a method to compress image (maintaining the aspect ration) or resize image before setting it to image view using picasso.Then set the converted drawable to imageview using picasso Target interface.

Comment: Thx for the help. After trial and error, I decided to download the image without fit() or resize, and just load the image into new Target, then setImageBitmap into the ImageView. Then in xml file, I set the scale type as centerCrop.
I think it is not efficient as it requires downloading the image without resizing. Yet I found that if I use fit() or resize(), the image will simply not show. I do not what is wrong with Picasso...
Thanks again.

Comment: @Derekyy I don't think fit() method make you request smaller size image from server (unless you write custom RequestTransformer). It just try to resize downloaded image so it will fit into ImageView. There should be no difference in terms of network usage whether you do or donot use fit() method.

Comment: @Derekyy did you ever find a solution? I have the same problem although for me it is with some specific images that never load whenever fit() is called but load otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [bug](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/881) that is reported to be fixed in the next release of the lib.

You can clone the repo of the lib and compile your own jar or wait.

I recommend you to take a look at Glide. Migrating from Picasso is quite trivial, it has better performance and it makes a nice smooth scrolling on lists.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problemm when i tried to use Picasso to load images but i used this [Library](https://github.com/koush/ion)

Its the simplest thing so far by me.

Compile:

```
compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
```

Then:

```
//for activity
ImageView myImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_image);

//for fragment
ImageView myImage = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_image);


Ion.with(myImage)
.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
.error(R.drawable.error_image)
.load("http://example.com/image.png");
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thx, but it would be best if I could stay with Picasso at this moment.